# how to loop through xml file and save the result into a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, elementtree

I have a big xml file without knowing the exact structure of the file. I try to loop through the xml hierarchies and extract the results and put them into a dataframe. However, the code break down after parsed soome text. Error returned as

```
File:"c:\Python34\lib....\frame.py", line 4327, in append
  elif isinstance(other, list) and not isinstance(other[0], DataFrame):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is my code with python 3.4:

```
def getelements(fn):
    df = pd.DataFrame()    
    index = 0
    context = iter(ET.iterparse(fn, events=('start', 'end')))
    _, root = next(context) 
    for event, elem in context:
        if elem.tag=='ROW': 
            alist=[]
            index += 1
            c = elem.findall('COLUMN')

            for cl in iter(c):
                pair = (str(cl.get('NAME')), str(cl.text), index)
                alist.append(pair)

            df=df.append(alist)
       #print out something during the processing 
                print(df[ :index])
                print ("index=%s"%index)

    df.to_csv('jv2015.csv', sep=',', quotechar="'")
    return df
```

The XML file seems has "Row" as an element, under "Row", there are different numbers of "Column" element. for each "Column" element, there is an attribute "Name" and value of the attribute. For example
..

```
<Row>
 <Column name="xxx">value</Column>
 <Column name="yyy">value</Column>
  ...
</Row>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to capture the `start` event too? As per the docs: *" iterparse() only guarantees that it has seen the “>” character of a starting tag when it emits a “start” event, so the attributes are defined, but the contents of the text and tail attributes are undefined at that point. The same applies to the element children; they may or may not be present."*

Comment: you are right I do not need to capture the start event. I just use the method to parse the file without occupying too much memory.

Comment: Do you still encounter the error if you only capture the `end` event?

Comment: I do not need event control, I have changed the code as: for event, elem in ET.iterparse(fn):
        if elem.tag == "ROW":

Comment: The error message is `raise event File "C:\...\ElementTree.py" line 1239, in feed self._parser.feed(data) File "<string>", in line None xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed(invalid token): line 1843394, column 49', what does the message mean?

Comment: If i catch 'end' event and match 'Row' tag, the parser catch no elements at all, return just None. I also find that it is the CDATA i need to deal with, in some CDATA text, they contain blank lines, which cause the problem.